# Reading and using a mixed variable type list from a file into a structure in C

Tags: c, arrays, file-io, structure

Ok, so I've been working on this for a while now. I want to read values from a .txt file and arrange then in a structure array. The data will be then be sorted and checked. The data is in the format:

Name,gender,height,weight

Tony,M,183.4,74.7

Jenny,F,134.7,65.9

my structure is set up like so:

```
`typedef struct patient patientInfo;
struct patient
{
    char name;
    char gender;
    float height;
    float weight;
};
patientInfo Data[300];`
```

The code to read the values into the array is the following:

```
int main(){
FILE *fptr=NULL;
int i = 0;


fptr = fopen("candidatesdata.txt","r");

if(fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to open patient info file.\n");
    }

while(fscanf(fptr,"%[^,],%[^,],%f,%f", &Data[i].name, &Data[i].gender, &Data[i].height, &Data[i].weight)!=EOF)
{
        i++;
}
```

I've managed to read and display the gender, weight, and age. But reading and displaying the name string is being quite problematic. I've been using the following to print the values:

```
for(i=0; i<=9; i++)
{
    printf("Name %d: %c \n",i+1, Data[i].name);
    printf("Gender %d: %c\n",i+1,Data[i].gender);
    printf("Height %d: %f\n",i+1,Data[i].height);
    printf("Weight %d: %f\n",i+1,Data[i].weight);

}
```

Everything works fine for all fields except the name field. I've tried defining the print statement differently (as string, int), but it seems the issue is whenever the name is being saved to the structure. I can't find any more examples outside of arrays for single variable types.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To format a string, you need to use `%s`.  To format an integer as a single character, you can use `%c`.

Comment: @TomKarzes I've used `%s` in the `fscanf` statement as well as in the `printf` statement, and both will turn up datatype errors when used. I'm not sure how else to set it other than the `%[^,]` to obtain the characters up to the comma.

Comment: You're declaring `name` as a single character.  That means you can only have one character for the name.  Instead, you need to make it a character array (e.g., `char name[MAX+1]` where `MAX` is the max name length), or a character pointer (e.g., `char *name`) in which case you need to use `malloc` to allocate storage for it.

Comment: @tomKarzes I originally tried to set the name as `char name[10]` , but then I would get a datatype error when declaring `%[^,]` in the `fscanf` statement. I have no idea how to get around that.. 

I've never used the `malloc` method with a pointer, could you elaborate on that?

Comment: If `data` is a character array, you don't use the address-of operator in `scanf`, just use `Data[i].name`.  That should fix the data type error.  But be warned, if you declare it as `name[10]`, then the maximum length name you can safely handle is 9 (you need the extra character for the terminating null byte).  So if you encounter a name of length 10 or more, you will overwrite memory and likely get a segmentation fault.

Comment: If you want to use `malloc`, then you would probably want to first read the name into a temporary buffer, then allocate the exact amount of storage for it with `malloc`, based on its length (and again, you'd add one to it for the terminating null byte).

Comment: @TomKarzes That did it!! Thank you so much, who would have known that operator was the only error. 

I really appreciate the hep, Thank you!

Comment: fix like [this](https://ideone.com/GQBc7s)